# Launch java program in the shell but write with eclipse?

Tags: java, console

is it possible to launch a program in my shell which I wrote with eclipse ?

For some reasons, I don't want to use the eclipse console so is it possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely. Export your program to a jar file (your-project.jar) and run the main function of the desired class by calling the command:

> java -cp your-project.jar packagename.classname

You can even redirect the outputs (stdout, stderr) to a file by:

> java -cp your-project.jar packagename.classname > outputFile 2>&1

Comment: Great, thank you! I suppose that I need to export everytime that I change my java project no ?

Comment: Yes, Exporting again (which should be rather quick unless you have a mammoth project) will make sure that the jar file reflect your changes. Please also mark my original response as the correct answer if you feel it address your question.

Comment: Humm that's not cool because it's a repetitive action. Is it possible to write a script which does this exportation ?